# Can't assign variable shell script

Tags: shell, pipe

How to assign "time" variable like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "License"
read license
time=echo date +"%H:%M"
echo $license $time
```

when I run that script, the time variable is empty. But if I delete echo license and read license, it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to put `time=$(date +"%H:%M")`

Comment: In case you're wondering what your original command did, `time=echo date +"%H:%M"` runs `date +%H:%M` (output undirected, thus going to stdout and not stored) with the variable `time` exported in the environment with the value `echo`.

Comment: I got this output using your code:

License
N
N date +%H:%M

Comment: @FirmanAli, that sounds like you didn't follow Thronghar's suggestion _precisely_. Perhaps you failed to drop the `echo`?